# writing a simple cleanup landing pad on llvm

Tags: c++, exception, llvm

I have created a basic function `Foo1` that calls another one `Bar2` through invoke. The first instruction in the unwind cleanup basic block must be the landing pad:

```
void bar2()
{ 
  throw;
}
llvm::Function* Bar2Fn = llvm::Function::Create( voidSig , &bar2);
engine->addGlobalMapping( Bar2Fn, (void*)&bar2 );
llvm::InvokeInst* inv = builder.CreateInvoke( Bar2Fn , continueBlock, unwindBlock, llvmArgValues , "invoke");
builder.CreateBr(continueBlock);
builder.SetInsertPoint(unwindBlock);
llvm::LandingPadInst* landPadInst = builder.CreateLandingPad(...);
//add some cleanup code? where??
```

I have honestly no idea what i need to put between the parameters of `CreateLandingPad` in order to get a basic landing pad that invokes a custom clean up code for the current `Foo1` stack objects. `Bar2` might throw by calling c++ functions that themselves throw (or rethrow an existing exception)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I admit I have little experience here, but have you seen the exception demo code example? It seems to contain exactly the kind of sequence you are hoping to find.

Basically, you start by setting up the personality to behave as in C++:

```
llvm::Function *personality = module.getFunction("__gxx_personality_v0");
```

You then create the landingpad with that personality and define its type:

```
llvm::LandingPadInst *caughtResult = 
  builder.CreateLandingPad(ourCaughtResultType,
                           personality,
                           numExceptionsToCatch,
                           "landingPad");
```

Setting up the types to catch:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < numExceptionsToCatch; ++i) {
  // Set up type infos to be caught
  caughtResult->addClause(module.getGlobalVariable(
                          ourTypeInfoNames[exceptionTypesToCatch[i]]));
}
```

And signalling it's a cleanup handler:

```
caughtResult->setCleanup(true);
```

This is it, I believe; now you can get the exception itself:

```
llvm::Value *unwindException = builder.CreateExtractValue(caughtResult, 0);
```

The [ExceptionDemo.cpp](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/examples/ExceptionDemo/ExceptionDemo.cpp?view=markup&sortby=file) file, from which these code segments are taken, contains a fuller sequence; specifically, it shows how to check the type root of the caught exception and branch into a specific block - your cleanup code - when it matches something:

```
llvm::Value *retTypeInfoIndex = builder.CreateExtractValue(caughtResult, 1);

// FIXME: Redundant storage which, beyond utilizing value of
//        caughtResultStore for unwindException storage, may be alleviated
//        altogether with a block rearrangement
builder.CreateStore(caughtResult, caughtResultStorage);
builder.CreateStore(unwindException, exceptionStorage);
builder.CreateStore(ourExceptionThrownState, exceptionCaughtFlag);

// Retrieve exception_class member from thrown exception
// (_Unwind_Exception instance). This member tells us whether or not
// the exception is foreign.
llvm::Value *unwindExceptionClass =
  builder.CreateLoad(builder.CreateStructGEP(
           builder.CreatePointerCast(unwindException,
                                     ourUnwindExceptionType->getPointerTo()),
                                             0));

// Branch to the externalExceptionBlock if the exception is foreign or
// to a catch router if not. Either way the finally block will be run.
builder.CreateCondBr(builder.CreateICmpEQ(unwindExceptionClass,
                          llvm::ConstantInt::get(builder.getInt64Ty(),
                                                 ourBaseExceptionClass)),
                     exceptionRouteBlock,
                     externalExceptionBlock);
```

Finally, an additional example, along with explanations, is available [on the blog post that introduced the new exception handling mechanism](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/11/llvm-30-exception-handling-redesign.html).

Comment: that example ExceptionDemo is interesting, i didn't knew about it, thanks. Something that raises my attention is that the llvm::Function is created for `ourPersonality` and used in the landing pad, but i don't see anywhere a mapping from this function to the address of the actual `ourPersonality` function. Is `getFunction` doing symbol resolution by default if the mapping is empty?. I couldn't find any documentation for that 'feature'

Comment: @lurscher I don't know; I suspect it has something to do with the `_Unwind_Reason_Code` defined on its definition (which appears in the same file), but I'm just not familiar enough with that whole area, I'm afraid.